# differences between `flutter build aar --no-debug --no-profile` and `flutter build aar --release`

Tags: flutter

can anyone let me know the differences between

```
 flutter build aar --no-debug --no-profile
```

and

```
flutter build aar --release
```

1. i only want a release one.

```
--[no-]debug                    Build a debug version of the current project.
                                    (defaults to on)
--[no-]profile                  Build a version of the current project specialized for performance profiling.
                                    (defaults to on)
--[no-]release                  Build a release version of the current project.
```

2.i have read the documentation above,and i think both the commands above will produce a release aar only,but it's not. the command with "no" is right,and the second one will produce debug、profile、and release.
3. i have read this issue [flutter build aar --release ,--release not work](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47762) and it was closed with this unsatisfactory answer https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47762#issuecomment-582223344 and this way new question comes out "differences between `flutter build aar` and `flutter build aar --release`"

Answer (score 0):

```
right, sorry - by default it builds all variants. so build aar --release and build aar do the same thing. You need to disable debug and profile with build aar --no-profile --no-debug
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/115051#issuecomment-1309706377